# How to trigger an useEffect hook in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to make an app that receives an ID for a product from the user, then finds the product from the database and updates the product on the screen. I receive the ID by using an `useState` and an input box. The `GetProduct` component gets called, and the ID is passed to it through `Props`. It fetches the product by that ID (using an `useEffect`) and returns that product. 
 **The problem:** 
 The `useEffect` fetches the product once when the app starts (when the ID is still empty), and when the ID gets updated, the product won't update again.
App.tsx:

```
function App() {
const [id, setId] = useState("")
 const onChangeHandler = (event: { target: { value: React.SetStateAction<string> } }) => {
    setId(event.target.value)
}
return(
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
        value={id}
      />
      <GetProduct id={id}></GetProduct>
    </div>
)
```

`GetProduct` Component:

```
import { Product } from "../api/dto/product.dto"
import productService from "../services/product.service"

interface Props {
    id: string
}

export const GetProduct: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {  
    const [product, setProduct] = useState<Product>()
    useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchOne() {
        const response = await productService.getOne(props.id)
        setProduct(response.data)
      }
      fetchOne()
    }, [])
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          {product?.title}, {product?.description}, {product?.price}
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
```

Comment: change `}, [])` for `}, [product])` or change `}, [])` for `}, [props.id])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `props.id` to dependency array so it would rerun on id change. Having an empty dependency array makes it run only once.

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchOne() {
    const response = await productService.getOne(props.id)
    setProduct(response.data)
  }
  fetchOne()
}, [props.id])
```

Comment: Thanks, silly me- I should've known this.
I just have started learning React and This is my first React project, there are a lot of things I should learn.

Comment: welcome. the learning list never ends. learning by building a project is a good way. good luck!